# Angular6 - ngIf does not destroy object

Tags: angular, angular6, form-control

I have a parent component that will change the child's form that is passed as `@Input()` when a button is clicked. I use `ngIf` to render the child component, but when I click to change the form, the child component does not get destroyed and recreated.

parent.component.ts

```
form: FormGroup;
showChildForm: boolean;
num: number;

ngOnInit(){ 
   this.showChildForm = false; 
   this.num = 1;
   this.form = new FormGroup({group:{'name', new FormControl('name'+this.num,[])}})
}

changeForm(){
   this.num += 1;
   this.showChildForm = true; 
   this.form = new FormGroup({group:{'name', new FormControl('name'+this.num,[])}})
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<button (click)="changeForm()"></button>
<child *ngIf="showChildForm" [form]="form"></child>
```

child.component.ts

```
@Input() form: FormGroup;
```

child.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <input type="text" [formControl]="form.get('name')"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't have time to really give this much thought, but I just wanted to point out that you're binding to an object.  The parent then changes the reference to the object without actually changing the object.  I wouldn't expect the child to recognize that anything has changed.

Comment: There is no ngIf in the code you provided. Please recreate problem in a stack blitz.

Comment: @danday74 lololol

Comment: @danday74 Sorry about that. I just added it.

Comment: You can't destroy a child element using *ngIf that is being use by another element. I literally discovered that yesterday

Comment: why do you want to destroy it in first place? isn't changing the input enough?

Comment: @Ludevik the form is updated, but the input value does not get updated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside changeForm you are not setting this.showChildForm to false again.

Try doing this:

```
changeForm(){
  this.num += 1;
  this.showChildForm = false; 
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.showChildForm = true; 
    this.form = new FormGroup({group:{'name', new FormControl('name'+this.num,[])}})
  })
}
```

toggling it off and then back on again in the next tick cycle (using setTimeout) will cause the component to be destroyed and recreated.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. In my opinion using `changeDetector` is more elegant than `setTimeout`

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef){}

changeForm() {
    this.num += 1;
    this.showChildForm = false;

    // now notify angular to check for updates
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();    
    // change detection should remove the component now

    // then we can enable it again to create a new instance
    this.showChildForm = true; 
    this.form = new FormGroup({group:{'name', new FormControl('name'+this.num,[])}})
}
```